# Find the area of overlap between two shapes?

Tags: java, opencv

I am currently working on a project to detect whether vehicles are using the railway track of a level crossing. Right now, I'm doing this by demarcating the railway track as a `MatOfPoint` and identifying each vehicle as a `Rect`. My next step from here is to work out the area of overlap between the `MatOfPoint` (railway line) and the `Rect` (vehicles). Thus, if 50% of a `Rect` shares its area with the `MatOfPoint`, it's very likely that a vehicle is using the level crossing.

How can I find the area of this intersection? Does OpenCV have any functions which allow this?

Comment: draw each shape filled white on its own single channel black image. then use Mat AND operator to get an image with the overlapping area.

Comment: @Micka Okay, but how do I then find the area of the overlapping area?

Comment: use findContours and use cv::contourArea or just count nonblack pixels in the overlap image.

Comment: if you only use cv::Rect instead of arbitrary shapes it is very simple btw: cv:: Rect overlap = rect1 && rect2; float area = overlap.width*overlap.height; (in c++)

Comment: Why do you use MatOfPoints? It is [not even anymore documented](http://docs.opencv.org/search.html?q=matofpoint)...